# Docker + ReactJS + Webpack Hot-reload + Django

Tags: django, webpack, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

Webpack hotreload creates a static asset/bundle that usually is picked up by Django's collectstatic command. Since I have this setup dockerized, I'm looking for advice on how to get the hotreload working on a docker host. Specifically, when I change some code in the React App, Webpack should generate a bundle and I should be able to visit http://DOCKER_MACHINE_IP to see the hot-reload. I'm hoping to use volumes to persist the bundles, but can I call collectstatic multiple times? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? It would seem something very useful to many people including me.